# Razor en VB y llenado de Carousel por medio de lista de objetos

Tags: html, vb.net, asp, razor

Llevo un proyecto en el cual hice un carousel que se esta alimentando de una lista de objetos y hacen fill a un card, que luego entra al mismo carousel.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema cuando mi lista es de cantidad de numero no
MOD 3, luego de la primer Slide empiezan a imprimirse de manera no unifome (un card por slide, dos por slide, todas las cards en un slide, etc o no se imprime)
He intentado de distintas maneras pero solo no hace fill como debería y el propósito es que sean dinámicas dentro del carousel

### **No me deja publicar código porque son una cadena de IFs algo extensas**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**UPDATE** 
he intentado asi

```
        For j = 1 To GestionesCount Step 1
        CardContador += 1
        If CardContador Mod 3 = 0 And SlideContador = 0 Then
            For Each oGestion In lGestiones.GetRange(1, 3)
                CardHtml = CardHtml & "<div class='slide-card' onclick='" & "location.href=" & "'Tyc18.aspx'" & ";'  >" &
                    "<h5 class='slide-card__title'>" & oGestion.NombreGestion & "</h5>" &
                    "<i class='slide-card__icon " & oGestion.Icono & "'></i>" &
                    "<p class= 'slide-card__p'>" & oGestion.DescripcionGestion & "</p>" &
                    "</div>"
            Next
            ItemCarousel = ItemCarousel & "<div class='carousel-item active' data-bs-interval='5000'>" &
                                           "<div class='d-block w-100'>" &
                                           "<div class='slide__container-cards justify-content-center pb-5 pt-2'>" &
                                           CardHtml &
                                           "</div>" &
                                           "</div>" &
                                           "</div>"
            CardHtml = ""
            SlideContador += 1
        ElseIf CardContador Mod 3 = 0 And SlideContador >= 1 Then
            For Each oGestion In lGestiones.GetRange(j - 3, 3)
                CardHtml = CardHtml & "<div class='slide-card' onclick='" & "location.href=" & "'Tyc18.aspx'" & ";'  >" &
                                    "<h5 class='slide-card__title'>" & oGestion.NombreGestion & "</h5>" &
                                    "<i class='slide-card__icon " & oGestion.Icono & "'></i>" &
                                    "<p class= 'slide-card__p'>" & oGestion.DescripcionGestion & "</p>" &
                                    "</div>"
            Next
            ItemCarousel = ItemCarousel & "<div class='carousel-item' data-bs-interval='5000'>" &
                                               "<div class='d-block w-100'>" &
                                               "<div class='slide__container-cards justify-content-center pb-5 pt-2'>" &
                                               CardHtml &
                                               "</div>" &
                                               "</div>" &
                                               "</div>"
            CardHtml = ""
            SlideContador += 1

        End If

    Next j
```

Comment: Escribe el código _como texto, con formato_. No es necesario que escribas todo el código, sino un [repro]. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre Solucionar de esta manera

```
        For j = 1 To GestionesCount Step 1
        CardContador += 1
        If CardContador Mod 3 = 0 And SlideContador = 0 Then
            For Each oGestion In lGestiones.GetRange(0, 3)
                CardHtml = CardHtml & "<div class='slide-card' onclick='" & "location.href=" & "'Tyc18.aspx'" & ";'  >" &
                    "<h5 class='slide-card__title'>" & oGestion.NombreGestion & "</h5>" &
                    "<i class='slide-card__icon " & oGestion.Icono & "'></i>" &
                    "<p class= 'slide-card__p'>" & oGestion.DescripcionGestion & "</p>" &
                    "</div>"
            Next
            ItemCarousel = ItemCarousel & "<div class='carousel-item active' data-bs-interval='5000'>" &
                                           "<div class='d-block w-100'>" &
                                           "<div class='slide__container-cards justify-content-center pb-5 pt-2'>" &
                                           CardHtml &
                                           "</div>" &
                                           "</div>" &
                                           "</div>"
            CardHtml = ""
            SlideContador += 1
        ElseIf CardContador Mod 3 = 0 And SlideContador >= 1 Then
            For Each oGestion In lGestiones.GetRange(j - 3, 3)
                CardHtml = CardHtml & "<div class='slide-card' onclick='" & "location.href=" & "'Tyc18.aspx'" & ";'  >" &
                                    "<h5 class='slide-card__title'>" & oGestion.NombreGestion & "</h5>" &
                                    "<i class='slide-card__icon " & oGestion.Icono & "'></i>" &
                                    "<p class= 'slide-card__p'>" & oGestion.DescripcionGestion & "</p>" &
                                    "</div>"
            Next
            ItemCarousel = ItemCarousel & "<div class='carousel-item' data-bs-interval='5000'>" &
                                               "<div class='d-block w-100'>" &
                                               "<div class='slide__container-cards justify-content-center pb-5 pt-2'>" &
                                               CardHtml &
                                               "</div>" &
                                               "</div>" &
                                               "</div>"
            CardHtml = ""
            SlideContador += 1
        End If
        If CardContador = lGestiones.Last().NumeroGestion Then
            If lGestiones.Last().NumeroGestion Mod 3 = 1 Then
                For Each oGestion In lGestiones.GetRange(CardContador - 1, 1)
                    CardHtml = CardHtml & "<div class='slide-card' onclick='" & "location.href=" & "'Tyc18.aspx'" & ";'  >" &
                                    "<h5 class='slide-card__title'>" & oGestion.NombreGestion & "</h5>" &
                                    "<i class='slide-card__icon " & oGestion.Icono & "'></i>" &
                                    "<p class= 'slide-card__p'>" & oGestion.DescripcionGestion & "</p>" &
                                    "</div>"
                Next
                ItemCarousel = ItemCarousel & "<div class='carousel-item' data-bs-interval='5000'>" &
                                               "<div class='d-block w-100'>" &
                                               "<div class='slide__container-cards justify-content-center pb-5 pt-2'>" &
                                               CardHtml &
                                               "</div>" &
                                               "</div>" &
                                               "</div>"
                CardHtml = ""
                SlideContador += 1
            ElseIf lGestiones.Last().NumeroGestion Mod 3 = 2 Then
                For Each oGestion In lGestiones.GetRange(CardContador - 2, 2)
                    CardHtml = CardHtml & "<div class='slide-card' onclick='" & "location.href=" & "'Tyc18.aspx'" & ";'  >" &
                                    "<h5 class='slide-card__title'>" & oGestion.NombreGestion & "</h5>" &
                                    "<i class='slide-card__icon " & oGestion.Icono & "'></i>" &
                                    "<p class= 'slide-card__p'>" & oGestion.DescripcionGestion & "</p>" &
                                    "</div>"
                Next
                ItemCarousel = ItemCarousel & "<div class='carousel-item' data-bs-interval='5000'>" &
                                               "<div class='d-block w-100'>" &
                                               "<div class='slide__container-cards justify-content-center pb-5 pt-2'>" &
                                               CardHtml &
                                               "</div>" &
                                               "</div>" &
                                               "</div>"
                CardHtml = ""
                SlideContador += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next j
```